# Rellenar DropDownListFor con modelo diferente al de la vista

Tags: html, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

Quiero rellenar un dropdownlist con un modelo diferente al que estoy usando en la vista. En la vista uso la entidad Noticia, y el dropdownlist se debería rellenar con la entidad Categoría. Trate de mandarlo con ViewBag pero me da error NullReferenceException. Les muestro un poco del código que tengo:

Noticia:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public int IdCategoria { get; set; }
public string Titulo { get; set; }
public string Contenido { get; set; }
public Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
```

Categoria:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Nombre { get; set; }
public string Descripcion { get; set; }
public bool Activo { get; set; }
```

Controlador de noticia:

```
public ActionResult RegistrarNoticia()
{
    ViewBag.DropDown = CategoriaLN.ListCategoria();
    return View();
}
```

Vista de noticia:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RegistrarNoticia", "Noticia", FormMethod.Post))
{                   
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdCategoria, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdCategoria, new SelectList(ViewBag.DropDown, "Id", "Nombre", Model.Categoria))
    </div>
}
```

Bueno si alguno tienen una sugerencia se lo agradecería mucho. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que este es tu problema:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdCategoria, new SelectList(ViewBag.DropDown, "Id", "Nombre", Model.Categoria))
```

El ultimo parametro te dice que valor es el que estas seleccionando, cambialo por null o por tu variable Model.IdCategoria

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdCategoria, new SelectList(ViewBag.DropDown, "Id", "Nombre", Model.IdCategoria))
```

Comment: Funciono, cambie el model por null, porque por IdCategoria tampoco funcionaba. Me podrias explicar un poquito mas por que pasaba eso? Gracias